# How do I replace individual letters from user input text

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create an encoder that changes text taken from the user into gibberish that doesn't mean anything. Like **word** to **umpb** . If you were to decrease each letter by 2 in the decoded message then you would get the encoded message of umpb and vice versa.

This is what I want to do:

1. Control the amount by which each letter gets jumbled. 1 for., 5 back., 3 for. etc.
2. Be able to do this not just on one word but entire paragraphs, all at once.

I don't know coding that much and I tried looking online for a piece of code that I could use to do this, but I couldn't find any. So, basically I'm askng if anyone can come and code this entire thing for me. If you can't code the entire thing for me I'd still like some help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body align = "center">

    <button onclick="myFunction()">function</button>
    
    <p id="function"></p>
    
    <script>
    
        function myFunction() {
            //var sub = prompt("Enter Subtraction");
            var text = prompt("Enter Text");
            var alpha = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
            
            
            document.getElementById("function").innerHTML = text;
        }
    
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I thought that I could replace each letter from the input individually, that's why alpha is there. But I realized that I don't even know how to do that. So let me know if I even need that array or if I should throw it away.

Comment: Are you looking to be able to encode and decode, or just obfuscate text?

Comment: You probably want to loop over each letter in the string and encode it, a simple way it to turn it into an array, then use [*map*] or [*reduce*] to encode each character and return the modified string like `[...string].map(char => somefn(char)).join('')`. Try something and if it doesn't work, update your question with what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this article is what you're looking for by Erica N: [JavaScript Algorithm: Letter Changes](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/javascript-algorithm-letter-changes-6182740d490d)

I've taken this and modified slightly.

```js
function encodeFunction() {
  var text = prompt("Enter Text");
  document.getElementById("function").innerHTML = LetterChanges(text);
}

function decodeFunction() {
  var text = prompt("Enter Text");
  document.getElementById("function").innerHTML = LetterChanges(text, false);
}

function LetterChanges(str, encode=true) { 
  let adjust = 1;
  if(!encode){
    adjust = -1;
  }
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  let strArray = str.split("");
  let letterChange = strArray.map(function(value, index, array){
    if(str.charCodeAt(index) < 97 || str.charCodeAt(index) > 122){
      return value
    }else{
      return String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(index)+adjust)
    }
  });
  
  return letterChange.join(""); 
}
```

```html
<button onclick="encodeFunction()">Encode String</button>
<button onclick="decodeFunction()">Decode String</button>

<p id="function"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much dude, this is exactly what I wanted. It was a weird ask but if it wasn't for gravity falls I wouldn't even be thinking of this stuff. Thanks again.

Comment: hey, thanks for the code. But can you tell me how to get real-time encoded and decoded text by writing in a text box. so that i dont have to wait for a prompt every time i want encode or decode a message. Thanks.